# What does `auto` implicitly map to?

Tags: c++, syntax, iterator

I am trying to solve a question on LeetCode (https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-matching-subsequences/description/).

The code I wrote with some online help was as follows:

```
class Solution {
public:

    //Reference: https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-matching-subsequences/discuss/117575/C++-12-Line-Solution-with-Explanation

    int numMatchingSubseq(string S, vector<string>& words) {
        vector<vector<int>> dict(26);
        for(int i=0; i<S.size(); i++)
            dict[S[i]-'a'].push_back(i);

        int counter=0;
        for(string& word: words) {
            int x=-1;
            bool found=true;

            vector<vector<int>>::iterator loc=dict.begin();
            for(const char& ch: word) {
                // auto loc=upper_bound(dict[ch-'a'].begin(), dict[ch-'a'].end(), x);
                loc=upper_bound(dict[ch-'a'].begin(), dict[ch-'a'].end(), x);
                if(loc==dict[ch-'a'].end()) found=false;
                else x=*loc;
            }

            if(found) counter++;
        }

        return counter;
    }
};
```

The original code used the keyword `auto` as the data type of `loc`.  As per my understanding, `loc` should be an iterator of `vector<vector<int>>()`, since `upper_bound()` returns an iterator as per cppreference.com (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound).

However, declaring `loc` as an `iterator` to `vector<vector<int>>` gives me a compilation error:

> Line 19: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >}' and '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >')

Could someone please point out the type of `loc`?

Thanks.

Note:

1. I am not including the question description as I don't think that is needed at all because I am asking a syntactical question.
2. I know I can obviously use an `auto`.  However, I don't want to.

Comment: `std::upper_bound` returns whatever iterator type you give it, and you did not give it `std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator`s.

Comment: @nwp, could you please elaborate?  This is something new to me!

Comment: Not wanting to use `auto` is a bad argument, but wanting to understand the type anyway is good.

Comment: You're only passing it a `vector<int>::iterator`

Comment: @Tas, my motivation is the later.  `auto` is after all syntactical sugar and I wish to avoid eating it before I learn to use it in moderation.  Diabetes, you see! :)

Comment: To clarify these comments, `dict` is a `vector<vector<int>>`, but `dict[ch-'a']` is a reference to a `vector<int>`

Comment: @MichaelBurr, that helps.  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `decltype(dict[ch-'a'].begin()) loc;` makes more sense to you? It says to make `loc` the same type that `dict[ch-'a'].begin()` is.

Comment: @someone, please write a formal answer so that I could accept it.  Else I will delete (but it won't be available to future readers!)  Not that it is a good question, but still!

Comment: @nwp, got it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@nwp points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141553/what-does-auto-implicitly-map-to#comment85288561_49141553), [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) deduces its type based on its arguments. If you pass it a `vector<vector<int>>::iterator` than that's what it will return.

However, have a look at what you're actually passing:

```
loc=upper_bound(dict[ch-'a'].begin(), dict[ch-'a'].end(), x);
```

You're giving it `dict[char-'a'].begin()`. `dict` is a `vector<vector<int>>`, and so its `operator[]` returns a `vector<int>`, so you're only passing it a `vector<int>::iterator`. Therefore, you can rewrite it as:

```
vector<int>::iterator loc = upper_bound(dict[ch-'a'].begin(), dict[ch-'a'].end(), x);
```

Or simply use `decltype` or `auto`